# Searching file with PHP while loaded into memory?

Tags: php

Here's what I'm doing:

```
$address_db = file_get_contents("/root/addresses.txt");
```

And then:

```
if (strpos($address_db, $address) !== false) {
```

Basically the text file is being loaded into memory and my script is checking for strings in it.  Millions of strings are being checked and the file is about 5 GB, so this is the fasted way I've found do to this.

The problem is that if I have multiple instances running at the same time, then the `addresses.txt` is loaded into memory multiple times and causing my server to run out of memory.  Is there a way load the file into memory just once and have it used by multiple instances of my PHP script?

Comment: Can you use a DB? That would be considerably faster than this approach

Comment: Agreed, this is what a properly indexed database is for

Comment: Have you try to scan the file with `fgets` your file will be in memory via the cache disk so the io won't be huge

Comment: Or if you really want maybe try using a caching solution

Comment: probably you can use shared memory to load file into it https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.shmop.php

Comment: “The problem is that if I have multiple instances running”, then maybe don’t do that? Is this CLI or web? Once something is found, you don’t search for it again, ever, right? Are you accounting for subsets, “there” contains “the”, so the latter shouldn’t be searched for. Can you break the giant file into smaller files? If a database isn’t an option, have you looked into a queue at least?

Comment: you can use bash script to read the file and output it into different file or you can use exec and run your bash command. More over "multiple instances running ?" do you mean multiple ec2 instance ?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your use case than "matching strings" so that we can offer advice that's better suited to accomplishing that task in an efficient manner.